# How to stop google spreadsheet from splitting data automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to split the below data into responses for each question.
{"question_2":{"1":"5","2":"0","3":"7","4":"8","5":"9","other_comment":""},"question_3":{"1":"0","2":"11","3":"0","4":"0","5":"0","other_comment":""},"question_4":{"sub_question":{"15":"2","16":"3","17":"2"}},"question_5":{"option":"3"},"question_6":{"option":"3"}}

The moment I use Data-->Split text to columns, Spreadsheet automatically splits the data using "comma" as the separator.

But I want to use a custom separator **,"q** but I am unable to apply this custom separator after the data is already split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select **Data|Split text into columns** you should see a drop-down saying **Separator:Detect automatically**. If you use the up/down arrows to change **Detect Automatically** to **Custom**, you can put in any character or combination of characters you choose.

You can also use SPLIT as mentioned by  I'-'I but you have to remember to put the third parameter as FALSE to specify the whole string "q and not the individual characters " and q. Use "" to get a " within a string.

```
=split(A1,"""q",false)
```